# How to make function overloading with string literal types?

Tags: typescript, types

I'm not sure about the title, if anyone has anything better let me know.

I have this type:

```js
export type FooMedia = "course" | "article" | "podcast";
```

And then I have a function that receives a string of that type and based on the string passed have a different return type.

The overloads:

```js
function getFoo(
  id: string,
  type: "article"
): Promise<AxiosResponse<Article, any>>;

function getFoo(
  id: string,
  type: "podcast"
): Promise<AxiosResponse<Podcast, any>>;

function getFoo(
  id: string,
  type: "course"
): Promise<AxiosResponse<Course, any>>;
```

Function implementation:

```js
function getFoo<T extends FooMedia, R extends Media>(id: string, type: T> {
...
return axios.get<R>(endpoint);
}
```

But then, when I call it in a function like so:

```
function bar(type: FooMedia) {
 return getFoo("t", type);
}
```

I get an error saying

> FooMedia is not assignable to parameter of type '"article"'( and the rest of the types, *"podcast"* and *"course"*).

The intended behaviour is that based on the `FooMedia` type passed into the call, I get the correct return type.

Is this possible?

Comment: You probably want one generic call signature instead of multiple overloads (although you can still use an overload to implement the function), like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpL7pm).  If that meets your needs I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz That was exactly what I was looking for! Amazing.
You can write up the answer and I'll mark it as the right one :)
Is the `keyof` and the map the reason this works or could it be done another way?

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'd *like* to do is make `bar()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of the `type` parameter, like so:

```
function bar<K extends FooMedia>(type: K) {
  return getFoo("t", type); // error!
}
```

But unfortunately TypeScript doesn't really know how to perform the higher order analysis on [overloaded functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) in order to figure out how to deal with `getFoo("t", type)` for generic `type`.

Overloads are good for the situation when you explicitly call it with code statically known to match one of the call signatures.  Anything else is pretty much beyond the compiler's abilities.

You can call `getFoo("", "article")` is fine because the compiler can resolve that to the `getFoo(id: string, type: "article"): Promise<Article>;` call signature.

But `getFoo("", Math.random()<0.5 ? "article" : "course")` is *not* fine.  You get an error that no overload matches the call.  The compiler doesn't propagate the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the second parameter through to a union of call signatures (this is requested at [microsoft/TypeScript#14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107)).  And the same problem happens with `getFoo("", type)` for generic `type`.  Since `type` isn't known to be exactly one specific acceptable value, the compiler doesn't know which call signature to use, and it gives up.

You can "fix" it and avoid the error in `bar()` by adding a call signature that works for the union type of the type:

```
// add this signature
function getFoo(
  id: string, type: FooMedia
): Promise<AxiosResponse<Course | Article | Podcast, any>>;
```

but TypeScript doesn't synthesize or infer generic call signatures from specific ones so you'd get a union out:

```
function bar<K extends FooMedia>(type: K) {
  return getFoo("t", type); // no error, but
}

const z = bar("course");
// const z: Promise<AxiosResponse<Course | Article | Podcast, any>>
```

Overloads are unfortunately not the tool for the job.

---

If you want `bar()` to be generic and have it call `getFoo()`, then `getFoo()` should also be generic.  You can almost always turn an overloaded function call signature set into a single generic one, but in the general case it's kind of annoying.  Say you had this:

```
declare function ovld(x: string, y: number): boolean;
declare function ovld(x: number): string;
declare function ovld(x: boolean, y: string): number;

ovld(3).toUpperCase();
ovld(true, "abc").toFixed(2);
```

You could refactor to an input-output mapping type like

```
type CallSignatures =
  { i: [x: string, y: number], o: boolean } |
  { i: [x: number], o: string } |
  { i: [x: boolean, y: string], o: number };
```

And write a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to extract the output for a given input:

```
type Out<C extends { i: any[], o: any }, I extends any[]> =
  C extends unknown ? I extends C['i'] ? C['o'] : never : never;
```

And test it out:

```
declare function gnrc<I extends CallSignatures['i']>(...args: I): Out<CallSignatures, I>;
gnrc(3).toUpperCase();
gnrc(true, "abc").toFixed(2);
```

That works, but it's kind of yucky.  However in *this* case we can simplify considerably.  All the call signatures look the same except for a single string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) input parameter.  And the output types are also the same except for a type that's a function of that string literal input type.  And TypeScript already has great support for a mapping from string literal inputs to arbitrary outputs... it's called an [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces):

```
interface FooMap {
  course: Course,
  article: Article,
  podcast: Podcast
}
type FooMedia = keyof FooMap;

declare function getFoo<K extends FooMedia>(
  id: string,
  type: K
): Promise<AxiosResponse<FooMap[K], any>>;
```

That's very straightforward.  Now, if you want, you can still *implement* this as an overload, albeit one with a single call signature:

```
// call signature
function getFoo<K extends FooMedia>(
  id: string,
  type: K
): Promise<AxiosResponse<FooMap[K], any>>;

// implementation
function getFoo(id: string, type: FooMedia) {
  return null!;
}
```

People do that sort of thing when the compiler can't verify that the implementation matches the call signature, since overload implementations are checked more loosely than regular function implementations.  Okay,  let's see if `bar()` works now:

```
function bar<K extends keyof FooMap>(type: K) {
  return getFoo("t", type);
}

// function bar<K extends keyof FooMap>(
//   type: K): Promise<AxiosResponse<FooMap[K], any>>
```

The inferred return type is nice and generic now, which means calling `bar()` should result in the types you want:

```
const z = bar("course");
// const z: Promise<AxiosResponse<Course, any>>
```

Hooray!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDEFcDsGMBcCWB7ap7NJADgEwIbwCmo+ayARgFZEIDkAzqAG74A2kJFAnqANZFuAWABQRAB7ZkAJ3ihYqBnJwFiANXacAQtwDSg0AF5QAHgCSAGlC7QE4tFxMB3ZADNQZgHwAKUaH+glFQAXB4WfgHOACrIAKp4hEShuuEiAaDQRADuGhxJHgDaugC6oKIAlEaeoADeEf5BBdFxCcSlxpk5mkQA3KIAvn0ioiCgAMLsbIjQAOboABYkrjAIKNCiKom52nqCvmkBdQfp-oi4oQCMAEwAzKknAdD4ALb5AEQAysivoAByyMQ3vcHqBEAwAArSRCsYihVzsBhEYH+frI0BvM5A+ro6AA0gZSDPChEaRvUCjEnSGQAQlAAEFpDNCURoHI3OhuNgSIx4FDZnRQUxcXJ8AwGIgZk8KGwSBhQNh8NIXkRiNJAu54JzudBCcTpHQAHQVHpAA)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much for the detailed answer.
I just had some one question, about the part where you say: *"(...) mapping from string literal inputs to arbitrary outputs ... it's called an interface"*. Is there an advantage of using `interface` over `type`?

Comment: I don't think there's much of an advantage one way or the other.  You can use an alias of an anonymous object type if you prefer.  Most of the time an `interface` and a `type` alias of the same structure behave identically; there are some differences but they are certainly out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an extra declaration for your general form.

Something similar to this:

```
function getFoo(id: string, type: FooMedia): Promise<AxiosResponse<Media, any>>;
```

Here's a complete example. I assumed that `Media` is a union type.

```
type Article = {}
type Podcast = {}
type Course = {}

type Media = Article | Podcast | Course;

export type FooMedia = "course" | "article" | "podcast";

function getFoo(
  id: string,
  type: "article"
): Promise<Article>;
function getFoo(
  id: string,
  type: "podcast"
): Promise<Podcast>;
function getFoo(
  id: string,
  type: "course"
): Promise<Course>;
function getFoo(id: string, type: FooMedia): Promise<Media>;
function getFoo<T extends FooMedia, R extends Media>(id: string, type: T) {
    return {id} as unknown as R
}

function bar(type: FooMedia) {
 return getFoo("t", type);
}
```

and the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTsAlgYwDbQLxQN4F8CwAUKJFAAoD2AJsgIYDOwUWeRJ0AwhQK5z2Y4ChNuGgBZCFUS1msBCnRQAPuWp1GyqF178A3ESIQAHmAoIo7KADEKFCVJlYARMh58ITzU9ry0Hr6Y0DMBO+sKEAGbcAHbISBTRUADmEMA2FAAURFBQiFQAXFCMcIjRSQA02Raihd6+6E5EAJSFZHAUALaI-AA88Eh+AHxhUbHxiSlptlmEOXmFxaUVVey1geohza3tXb2UQYzDRKNxiAnJqekzcwVFwCVllbPVkLWuOh5b5DvdED3a7iOkRip3Okyu8zuDwqLwghXS9mkLW+nV+PURtCBJ3GFymFB6ABUoMZgBBolR6NZbBjylAAErEoyk8mUjGDDKQxaPWGFAlNHBVHJwVK8RLYPK4KAMKAxADW0QoAHdEtK6UQhMcQTiAEY+DKrKl2SRIgWzYXAUW4q5OEK09hNMJCIA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still have one question. When calling `bar` like so, `bar("course")` the return type will always be `Media`. That means that the other more specific declarations aren't needed. But what I wanted was based on the type that the return value would match.
Say type is `course` then the return type would be `Promise<Course>` and not just `Media`.